# How to make `npm install <package_a>` actually install `@myfancyname/package_a`

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

Let's say I published few years back a npm package `package_a`.

Now I actually "namespaced" all my packages under `@myfancyname/package_a`.

Is there a way to transform `package_a` install process so that

`npm install -g package_a`

actually just run

`npm install -g @myfancyname/package_a`

(of course this should work also for `npm install package_a` -> `npm install @myfancyname/package_a`)

This might be bad practice, so please advice in this case as well.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: It's likely that the best solution is to use [`npm deprecate`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-deprecate) on your old package to provide people with a message directing them to the new package name.

This [issue in the npm issue tracker](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/7515) suggests contacting support@npmjs.com. The issue is quite old, though, and also only seems to suggest contacting support for a large number of packages. Although the issue may be out of date, if there's a better way to do things, I'm sure the support team would redirect you there.

That said, while that npm issue title asks about a redirect (implying, to me at least, automatic redirect like what you want), the answers seem to be more about "redirecting" by informing users. Chances are, that's the recommended way, for better or worse. So you can use [`npm deprecate`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-deprecate) on your old package to provide people with a message directing them to the new package name.